Is there a way to disable adding a "CLOSING NOTE" when the note buffer is empty?
I have (setq org-log-done 'note) in my settings. Now when I finish a TODO task, I am prompted to enter a note. When I'm done I can press C-c C-c and whatever I typed in the buffer gets saved as a CLOSING NOTE entry.
The above scenario is the happy path. However sometimes I press C-c C-c without typing in anything (forgetting that I'm supposed to press C-c C-k to cancel). Org still saves the empty buffer and adds a CLOSING NOTE entry.
Is there a way to tell Org to avoid adding such meaningless CLOSING NOTE entries, when the buffer for the note is empty, even when I press C-c C-c? This way, I could also just press C-c C-c every time, without having to think to decide between C-c C-c and C-c C-k. In fact another related annoyance is that sometimes I do type in a note but press C-c C-k by accident and Org just throws away the note and I lose it; it would be great to avoid this behavior (by making C-c C-c automatically choose between saving the note if the buffer is non-empty, and discarding the note and cancelling the addition of the CLOSING NOTE if the buffer is empty). To summarize, make C-c C-c do the right thing automatically based on the buffer contents instead of asking the user to choose (and introduce human error).
I've looked at org-add-note (and org-store-log-note) which appear to be responsible for saving the CLOSING NOTE bits but I'm not quite sure how to advice-add around it to make it behave as I want.

The key function is org-store-log-note: it is called (indirectly1) by org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c (which is bound to C-c C-c in Org mode buffers) and also by org-kill-note-or-show-branches (which is bound to C-c C-k in Org mode buffers). The only difference between the two calls is that in the second (kill) case, the function is called with the global, dynamically scoped variable org-note-abort let-bound to t.
But that gives us an "in": even in the first ('store') case, we can check if the buffer is (more-or-less) empty and if so, set org-note-abort to t before calling org-store-log-note. And we can do that with an around advice.
Here's the implementation:
(defun my/org-log-note-buffer-empty-p ()
  "Is current buffer empty except for the boilerplate template at the top?"
  (eq (point-max) 85))

(defun my/org-store-log-note (orig-fun)
  (let ((org-note-abort (or org-note-abort (my/org-log-note-buffer-empty-p))))
    (apply orig-fun nil)))

(advice-add 'org-store-log-note :around #'my/org-store-log-note)


You can use a more sophisticated function to check if the buffer is empty but unless you are trying to be deliberately malicious, the simple function is probably enough.

Footnotes:
[1] If you go looking, look for org-finish-function: that's a global (dynamically bound) variable which is set to org-store-log-note by org-log-add-note. The function is then called, using funcall, from two places: from org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c which is called when you press C-c C-c, and from org-kill-note-or-show-branches which is called when you press C-c C-k.

This is brilliant, thanks! I ended up tweaking org-note-abort to just be (my/org-log-note-buffer-empty-p) (not (or org-note-abort (my/org-log-note-buffer-empty-p))) to make C-c C-k always save the note if it wasn't empty, to cover those cases where I pressed C-c C-k by accident instead of C-c C-c. IOW, now org-store-log-note always saves the note if I wrote something in it, and discards it if I didn't. Cheers!

The only "gotcha" is when you type a note and decide you don't want to keep it. And the boilerplate text will be wrong (if you decide to modify it, don't forget to modify that magic 85 above :-) )

> The only "gotcha" is when you type a note and decide you don't want to keep it.
Exactly. My take is that this "gotcha" is infinitely preferable to the default "gotcha" of just losing information if you press C-c C-k by accident.
WRT the magic 85 number, yup of course that can be smarter but I'm too lazy to fix. FWIW you can see my final version of it here: https://github.com/listx/syscfg/commit/d1923288ee14b5a3de06932a626f109ac3b9cb3f
